# Full text searching refuses to work without quotation marks

Tags: sql, sql-server, full-text-search

But at the same time, the quotation marks break the query if they are substituted in.

I have this query:

```
SELECT * FROM CONTACT1 WHERE CONTAINS(COMPANY, N'Aktie')
```

This returns no results. However, if I change this query to...

```
SELECT * FROM CONTACT1 WHERE CONTAINS(COMPANY, N'"*Aktie*"')
```

Now I get the results I'm actually expecting. I presume this is due to using the asterisk as a wildcard, although I don't understand why the quotation marks fix things. In addition, if I put this code behind a stored procedure and pass *the exact same parameter*, `"*Aktie*"`, I will receive an error that states:

```
Syntax error near '"' in the full-text search condition '"'.
```

Why? I'm no SQL dev but I need to use full text searching as part of my current feature, and I can't find any concrete answers on this.

"Aktie" is part of a Swedish word, however the Swedish word should be recognized by an English word breaker.

As per request, code of the SProc.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE gr_fulltextsearch 
  @query nvarchar
AS
  SELECT * FROM CONTACT1 WHERE CONTAINS(COMPANY, @query)
GO
```

Test code:

```
EXEC gr_fulltextsearch @query='"*Aktie*"'
> Syntax error near '"' in the full-text search condition '"'.

SELECT * FROM CONTACT1 WHERE CONTAINS(COMPANY, N'"*Aktie*"')
> (result set of CONTACT1)
```

Comment: This may depend on your specific SQL- is it Oracle, MSSQL MySQL?

Comment: @jedrus07 He tagged the problem as SQL-Server.

Comment: NB to editor: changing contractions from "I'm" to "I am" does not count as an "improvement"

Comment: I do not quite get your problem. Can you post the code of your troublesome stored procedure?

Comment: @Mithrandir certainly, although I think you will be disappointed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your stored procedure should look like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE gr_fulltextsearch 
  @query nvarchar(100) 
AS
  SELECT * FROM CONTACT1 WHERE CONTAINS(COMPANY, @query)
GO
```

If you use `(n)varchar` it will be interpreted as `(n)varchar(1)`, so all your procedure and CONTAINS getting is '"', hence the error message! You should adjust the value 100 to some value that is better suited to your needs.

See, not disappointing at all! :-)

Comment: I'm getting de ja vu. I'm sure I solved this before. Thank you :)